# deferred promise value not updating/resolving/deferring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, promise

I have a controller function that creates something. When the function is called, a `setInterval` run to get the status of the item.

Here is the service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function myService($q) {
        let deferred = $q.defer();

        function createSomething(name) {
            Meteor.call('createSomething', name, (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                } else {
                    //value returned is the created item (id, name, status)
                    deferred.resolve(res);
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function getStatus(id) {
            Meteor.call('getStatus', id, (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                } else {
                    //statuses are queued, processing, created
                    deferred.resolve(res);
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return {
            createSomething: createSomething,
            getStatus: getStatus
        }
    }

    angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', myService);
})();
```

And here is the controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function myController($scope, myService) {
        let ctrl = this;

        ctrl.create = (name) => {
            myService.createSomething(name)
                .then((item) => {
                    ctrl.statusInterval = setInterval(() => {
                        myService.getStatus(item.data.id)
                            .then((status) => {
                                //status is always 'queued' :(
                                if (status.data.status === 'created') {
                                    clearInterval(ctrl.statusInterval);
                                    //do something
                                }
                            });
                    }, 5000);
                });
        };
    }

    angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
})();
```

When I check the value of the `response` in `getStatus` of the **service**, the status changes every time it is called (queue -> processing ... processing -> created). However, the value of `status` in the **controller** is always `queue`.

How do I get the promise value to resolve?

Comment: Uh, both `createSomething` and `getStatus` are attempting to resolve the same deferred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`createSomething()` and `getStatus()` need to create and return their own promise.  They can't share a promise and work properly in all cases.

In addition, they should create and return a unique promise each time they are called, not the same promise every time they are called.  Remember, promises are one-way state machines.  Once resolved or rejected, their state never changes, even if `resolve()` or `reject()` is called again on them.

Here's an example:

```
    function createSomething(name) {
        // create a unique deferred inside this function each time you call it
        let deferred = $q.defer();
        Meteor.call('createSomething', name, (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            } else {
                //value returned is the created item (id, name, status)
                deferred.resolve(res);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Oh. So I should set a `$q.defer()` for each function that returns a promise then. Thanks! It works now! :)